# hide output of nmcli network command

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I want to hide output of `nmcli network on`, but the command insists on outputing to screen.

```
> sudo nmcli network off && sudo nmcli network on >/dev/null 2>&1
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV UP): ens32: link is not ready
ADDRCONF(NETDEV UP): ens32: link is not ready
ens32 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex，Flow Control: None
ADDRCONF(NETDEV CHANGE): ens32: link becomes ready
```

I thired `>/dev/null, /dev/null 2>&1` and so on, but none works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of that is actually the output of the `nmcli` command. All four lines are *kernel log* messages that are being output to the system console ("out of band" if you like) – basically the same messages as you would see in `dmesg`.

If you want to reduce the amount of messages that the kernel outputs to console, either boot with the appropriate `loglevel=` kernel parameter or run `dmesg --console-level=` afterwards.

The default message level varies between Linux distros but is probably set to `loglevel=3` (`--console-level=info`) in your case. Raise it to `loglevel=4` (`--console-level=notice`) to hide those specific messages.